# Normalising image bands in google earth engine before classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, random-forest

I have an image that has four bands. Three of them are derived from Sentinel-2 to give NDVI, NDBI and SAVI. The fourth band is derived from a Sentinel 1 SAR image collection. The Sentinel 2 bands have pixel values in the range -1 to +1, but the Sentinel 1 band is in the range +2 to +17.

I want to take these four bands, together with some training samples, to generate a landcover classification.

Do I need to normalise all the pixel values (say 0 to 1) across all four bands, prior to running a classifier such as `ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest` or can the smile classifier handle regressors that are on a different scale?

Comment: I disagree that common distributions are desirable for ML algorithms. This rather defeats the point of high-dimensional, non-linear interactions. It is also quite unnecessary to rescale to common data ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any built-in algo in GEE can handle different scale features so different scale should not be a problem. But since this is also a machine learning algorithm providing a common distribution is good practice. I think the code below can help.

```
var min_max_dict = image.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
geometry: image.geometry(),
scale: 20
});

print(min_max_dict);
var norm_image = image.select('B3')
                 .unitScale(stats.get('B3_min'),
                                       stats.get('B3_max'));

Map.addLayer(norm_image,{},"normalized image B3");
```